# compact() not adding empty variables

Tags: php

Im trying to get a list of variables into an array (for an error reporting class), but if the variable is NOT set it is not being "compacted".

The below is extracts of the code:

```
$testVar1 = 123;
$testVar2 = 'ABC';

$ErrorArray = compact('testVar1', 'testVar2', 'notSetVar');
```

I then walk through the $ErrorArray with :

```
foreach($ErrorArray as $key => $value) {
    $TempErrorMessage .= '$'.$key.' == '.$value.' ---- ';
}
```

The resulting output is :

> $testVar1 == 123 ---- $testVar2 == ABC ----

The problem is, i would like to to output "notSetVar" as ""/NULL, as this is likely to be where my error is....

Any suggestions would be greatly welcomed!

Best Regards
Ford

Comment: [`compact()`](http://php.net/compact) not issuing a warning, if variable is undefined: `Any strings that are not set will simply be skipped`. Consider to write your own function for that.

Comment: Where does notSetVar come from?

Comment: notSetVar does not come from anywhere, it's just my example of an !issset variable (that in all honesty should never be there, but as this is for error reporting, there is a chance that i may find i missed one, or a system error caused it not to be set correctly )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to PHP doc
http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

compact creates an array containing variables and their values.

For each of these, compact() looks for a variable with that name in the current symbol table and adds it to the output array such that the variable name becomes the key and the contents of the variable become the value for that key. In short, it does the opposite of extract().

**Any strings that are not set will simply be skipped.**

So, it is not possible to pass variable via compact unless its set. My suggestion is, check variable before compact().

```
 $testVar1 = 123;
    $testVar2 = 'ABC';
    if (!isset($notSetVar) {
     $notSetVar = null;
   }

    $ErrorArray = compact('testVar1', 'testVar2', 'notSetVar');

var_dump($ErrorArray);
```

Comment: Thank you, i had not seen the part that said "Any strings that are not set will simply be skipped." my mistake. i'll work on another way :-)